# Responsive and full screen frameworks

Tags: javascript, css, web

I have been exploring some responsive frameworks. As far as I have noticed, even if the framework is responsive it still tries to stick with a max width. How about not having a max width and *always* have a **full screen + responsive view**. Which framework would be best for this?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? "What is the best X" questions usually get closed here. Maybe you could add examples from some frameworks, and ask if it's possible to make *them* behave the way you want?

Comment: If you don't want a max-width simply don't include one. Just use width:100% (or 95% or whatever) as your top level.

Comment: Sorry @bfavaretto. I will be more specific in future.

Comment: @BillyMoat, I think I can make some sense out of what you said. I was thinking on the same lines but just wanted to know if there is some framework made with this kind of setting as its default as I think more complications can actually result in doing so (not sure but will explore). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good feature list on the most popular:
http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php

I agree with you 100%. IMO A responsive framework should not be limited to the default 960-1000px.

For this reason I recommend Zerb Fondation 3 for this. You can easily make certain containers or divs full width or even make the complete framework full width (with one line of CSS) and not stick to the 1000px default. Generally I will make the header full width/100% same with footer and its easy with foundation. You cant do this with bootstrap as easily but of course you could do this with anyframe work I just find foundation works best for me making full width sites.

Comment: Very nice comparison. Thanks!